# Executing IronPython in C#

Tags: ironpython

Maybe I totally missed the point about the purposes of IronPython, but apart from allowing a Python coder to access the whole .Net Framework, is this allowing a C# coder to execute Python code?

[EDIT]

Just noticed I duplicated a question with a better answer from 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these Tutorials, which explain how to host IronPython from other .NET languages, C# in this instance.

- http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Hosting_IronPython_2
- http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Using_Python_Functions_from_CSharp

Comment: I wonder if a full Python library could be hosted, since this example shows how to run directly some lines of code from a string. Specifically wondering if I'll have to go through all the same requirement than those when I'm using CodeDom to execute C# code on the fly.

Comment: I don't know, I don't even know C# or IronPython. I just googled for you.